# Unable to check a checkbox via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a form on a page, with a checkbox input field.  I also have a table on the page with a column that has true/false values.  Each row in the table also has a checkbox with `id="selectedReviewTypeYear"`.  There is also a button with `id="getDataToEdit"`.

When the `getDataToEdit` button is clicked, the javascript checks to see if any `id="selectedReviewTypeYear"` boxes are checked.  If a box is checked, a div is opened up with form fields prepopulated based on the row selected.  If no boxes are checked, the div remains hidden.

My problem is that the checkboxes aren't getting checked when the table data is "true."  Here is the javascript:

```
    $('#getDataToEdit').on('click', function (){
    $('#reviewTypeTable').find('tr').each(function (){
        var row = $(this);
        if (row.find('input[id="selectedReviewTypeYearID"]').is(':checked')){
            var idx = table.row(this).index();
            var vReviewName = document.getElementById("editReviewTypeYear-name");
            var vAllowMultiple = document.getElementById("allowMultiple");
            var vAllowMultipleSpan = document.getElementById("allowMultipleSpan");
            vReviewName.innerHTML = table.cell(idx, 2).data();
            if (table.cell(idx, 3).data() == "true"){
                $("#allowMultiple").prop("checked", true);
                vAllowMultipleSpan.innerHTML = table.cell(idx, 3).data();
            }
            else {
                $("#allowMultiple").prop("checked", false);
                vAllowMultipleSpan.innerHTML = table.cell(idx, 3).data();
            }
            showHide.style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    })
});
```

For testing purposes, I added a `span` element to the form called `allowMultipleSpan`.  This was simply so I could see if the javascript is able to read the data in the table field, which it is.  When I select a row, then click the button, the div opens up with the `vReviewName.innerHTML` populated correctly as well as the `allowMultipleSpan` populated correctly.  However, the checkbox is not getting checked if the data is "true".

I am running JQuery 2.1.1.  So far, I have tried using the following variations of the script, all with the same result:

From the JQuery (1.6+) spec:

`$("#allowMultiple").prop("checked", true);`

From the jQuery (1.5-) spec:

`$("#allowMultiple").attr("checked", true);`

From the Javascript spec:

`document.getElementById("allowMultiple").checked = true;`

Here is the HTML for my form:

```
<div class="widget-header"><h3>Edit: <span id="editReviewTypeYear-name" style="color: blue"></span></h3></div>
                <div class="widget-content">
                    <form id="editReviewTypeYear-form" class="form-horizontal" url="submitReviewTypeYear.htm">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Allow Multiple: </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="allowMultiple" name="allowMultiple" />
                                <span id="allowMultipleSpan" style="color: blue"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions">
                            <button id="submitReviewTypeYear" type="submit">Save</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-small btn-warning reg-cancel" id="submitReviewTypeYear-cancel" type="button" name="Cancel" value="cancel">Cancel</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried  `if (table.cell(idx, 3).data() == true)`?

Comment: Where's the HTML for `getDataToEdit` and `reviewTypeTable`? Post a complete code example please. Also, what errors in the console do you get?

Comment: @LucasRodrigues - aaaaand that was it.  Any idea why that if test would change the result?  Like I said, the span was still being populated with the correct value, so from all indications it appeared as though the if test was firing off correctly.

Comment: @j08691 - none of that is necessary.  I provided all relevant code.

Comment: And there were no errors in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `if (table.cell(idx, 3).data() == true)`?

You were always getting the false condition because you were comparing a boolean with "true" as a string.

Comment: Oooooh, right.  Data types.  "I always mess up some mundane detail!"  Thanks again!